# MarkerSupportView in eclipse plugin raising "indirectly referenced from required .class files" error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

> I am facing the error "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

---

import org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.MarkerSupportView;

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerSupportView
{

    public CustomMarkerView(String contentGeneratorId) {
        super(contentGeneratorId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

> I have added the following code in plugin.xml for generating
>   CustomMarkerView.

---

```
<extension
        id="com.test.plugin.markers"
        name="VNR Markers"
        point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">

        <persistent value="true"></persistent>

        <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"></super>

        <attribute name="Name"></attribute>

    </extension>

    <!--creating new view for displaying the markers --> 

    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 

        <view 
             class="vnrcheck.handlers.CustomMarkerView" 
             icon="icons/issue.png" 
             id="com.test.customMarker" 
             name="VNR Markers View"> 
        </view>

    </extension >

    <extension  
        point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport"> 

        <markerContentGenerator 
            id="com.test.customMarkerGenerator" name="Custom Marker View">  

        <markerTypeReference 
            id="com.test.plugin.markers"/>   

        <markerFieldReference 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.locationField"/>  

        <markerFieldReference 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceField"/>

        <markerFieldReference 
            id="com.test.value"/> 

        <markerFieldReference 
            id="com.test.methodname"/> 
        </markerContentGenerator>

        <markerField
            class="vnrcheck.handlers.Description"
            id="com.test.methodname"
            name="Description">
        </markerField>

         <markerField
            class="vnrcheck.handlers.Justification"
            id="com.test.value"
            name="Justification">
         </markerField>

    </extension>
```

> ### Dependency files i have added in my project as follows.
>
> ### **Pacjkages:**
>
> ```
>  org.eclipse.ui,
>  org.eclipse.ui.part,
>  org.eclipse.ui.texteditor,
>  org.eclipse.ui.views.markers,
>  org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.internal
> ```
>
> ### **Plugins:**
>
> ```
>  org.eclipse.ui,
>  org.eclipse.core.runtime,
>  org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101",
>  org.eclipse.cdt;bundle-version="8.0.2",
>  org.eclipse.cdt.ui;bundle-version="5.3.2",
>  org.eclipse.cdt.core;bundle-version="5.3.2",
>  org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.7.2"
>
> I will be very thankful if anybody provide me the right solution.
> ```